# How to write a  constraint to validate a field based on data in external database in Orbeon Forms?

Tags: mysql, external, validation, orbeon

Can I write a constraint to validate the input against data on external Mysql? I have a text input and I want to validate it based on a SQL sentence in mysql table.
Is there an example of that?

Comment: Jose, Is this for a form you are creating with Form Builder, or are you writing code in XForms and running it in Orbeon Forms?

Comment: Im using Form Builder, but I can learn how to write XForm code directly if u can give me an example.. I need to solve this with any method..

Comment: Got it. I don't have an existing example of this that I can post here, but described how you can do it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Form Builder [services and actions](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/user-guide/form-builder-user-guide#TOC-Advanced%3a-services-and-actions) to, upon some action, call a service or run a SQL query, and use the result to populate the value of a field or the list of possible values users can select in a field (e.g. populate a drop-down with a dynamic of products retrieved from a database).

This feature isn't designed to be used for validation. However, depending on what type of validation you want to do, you could get it work for validation. For instance, say you have an input field used to capture a product code, and you want to verify that the value entered by users is indeed a product code you know about in your database. You could:

1. Run a SQL query that returns `true` if the product code is known and `false` otherwise.
2. Populate a hidden field with that result.
3. Write a constraint on the product code saying that is is valid only of the value of that other hidden field is `true`.